# Tails 1.2.2. "Could not determine whether an upgrade is avaiable from our website"

Tags: tails, error

For about 4 or 5 days I have received this error message every time I have started Tails.
I have restarted, changed computer, created a new USB with a new ISO image but still get the error message. Is this something to be worried about or does it relate to the forthcoming manual upgrade to Tails 1.2.3. ?

Comment: I've entered this as a comment because I am not absolutely certain ... but, I think you have guessed correctly. The security certificate for the Tails download site is about to expire, which was why version 1.2.2 was released when it was; i.e., so the certificate relevant to the 1.2.3 upgrade could be downloaded and verified (with 1.2.2) before the expiry of the old certificate. So 1.2.2 would now have a certificate that does not become relevant until 3 Jan 2015. Hence the apparent error message. I should also say that I receive the same message having upgraded from Tails 1.2.1 to Tails 1.2.2

Comment: That problem should be fixed now since the new certicate has already become valid. Do you still experience the error @Mabuse ?

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with Tails' update mechanism that has since been fixed. It shouldn't have happened since then, if it did please let the Tails developers [know](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/bug_reporting/index.en.html) as soon as possible